# Sequelize allownull constraint conditionally

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, database-migration

I need a migration in sequelize to change a column. How can I use allowNull constraint on a column based on the value of another column?
For example consider I have columns A and B. In the migration I wanna have something like below:

```
queryInterface.changeColumn('book', ['A'], {
     allowNull: false,
     where: { B: true } 
});
```

But as I see in the examples, we can't use 'where' in changeColumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use customValidator for this problem like this :

```
queryInterface.changeColumn('book', ['A'], {
  allowNull: true,
  validate: {
    customValidator(value) {
      if (value === null && this.B) {
        throw new Error("A not be null if B === true");
      }
    }
  }
});
```